# How to know which lines were selected from a DataTable

Tags: datatable, richfaces, rows, selected

I have a page with a "rich:DataTable". For each table row, added a checkbox to allow the user to select more than one line before excute an operation. How to retrieve the rows that were selected?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a boolean  , maybe called `selected` , to the POJO that represents a row for the `rich:DataTable` . And bind this boolean to the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` in the `<rich:column>` inside the `<rich:dataTable>`

For example , your beans , POJO and the view may look likes this:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{myBean.customerList}" var="customer">
  <rich:column>
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{customer.selected}" /> 
  </rich:column>    
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{customer.address}" />
  </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>


public class MyBean {

    private List<Customer> customerList;

    //getter and setter for the customerList
}


public class Customer{

    private boolean selected;
    private String name; 
    private String address;

    //getter and setter for the properties
}
```

To retrieve the rows that were selected , just iterate the `MyBean.customerList` and check if the `selected` property of the `Customer` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I decided otherwise. Added a "Map " and a column with "CheckBox" this way: "". By submitting the form, the lines of "Map" that are selected will get the Boolean property equal "true".

My Bean:

```
public class Bean<T extends Object> {
    private Map<T, Boolean> selectedRowsMap = new HashMap<T, Boolean>(0);
    ...
    public Set<T> getSelectedRows() {
        selectedRows.clear();
        for (T key : getSelectedRowsMap().keySet()) {           
            if (getSelectedRowsMap().get(key) == true){
                selectedRows.add(key);              
            }
        }

        return selectedRows;
    }
}
```

My XHTML:

```
<rich:dataTable>
    <rich:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedRowsMap[row]}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="${row.age}" />
    </rich:column>
    ...
<rich:dataTable>
```